# OpenSSH_5.3 have no prompt when user account expires

Tags: ssh, openssh

OpenSSH_5.3p1 clients will not print the following warning when a correct password is provided but it is expired: **Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator**.

It might confuse users since they do not know what is going on and why the password has not been accepted. You must add the parameter **ssh xx.xx.xx.xx -v**, the account expiration prompt will appear.

But OpenSSH_4.3p2 have the prompt when a correct password is provided but it is expired.

I want OpenSSH_5.3p1 clients to be able to print the warning message when user account expires. But i don't konw how to set up the OpenSSH_5.3p1 clients.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This sounds mostly like a comment. Are you looking to change a behavior somewhere?

Comment: I want OpenSSH_5.3p1 clients can print the warning message when user account expires. But i don't konw how to set OpenSSH_5.3p1 clients.

Comment: Such string was never in the `openssh` sources. Wasn't it PAM providing this message? Or some patched version from different vendor? Can you provide exact message you are getting in both cases?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I added 2 message in the above @Jakuje

Comment: It looks like you are using RHEL. Red Hat support should give you better answers than random people on the Internet. Though I would try to search and compare PAM stack (if RHEL5 was using PAM yet).